# Refactor angular module name in Webstorm

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea, refactoring, webstorm

Is there a possibility or trick to rename an angular module in Webstorm with refactoring in the whole project?

'Cause when I have something like this

```
angular.module('my-module', []);
```

and my caret is on the `'my-module'` string, I cannot refactor the module name.
Is there an appropriate place (or plugin) to define this, so it works right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only think of a global search and replace '⌘+SHIFT+r'
Maybe, but do share if it does the trick.

Comment: This obviously works, but having a rather big project with a lot of bower_components / node_modules and no option to exclude them isn't that nice. I just wish angularjs integration in Webstorm would be as nice as it is shown in their promotion videos. There is still a lot missing, imho.

Comment: ahh, but you might get away if you specify the path. Might be a two step process, depending on your file structure.  [link]https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html

Comment: It turnes out, that I actually can change the scope of the find and replace dialog. First generate a custom scope: http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/scopes.html and then add it in `Replace in Path` > `Scope` > `Custom` > `<myCustomScope>`

Comment: ahh cool! loving webstorm! thanks for sharing. good to know, but im still waiting on the 'Copyright profile' plugin/feature thats missing in Webstorm.